# D3.js table not refreshing when data changes

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm displaying a table in the browser using d3.json function. My table in the browser is not refreshing when data changes in the json file. It's showing previous data instead of new data in the table. If I refresh manually in the browser then it works correctly the table changes with new data.

Here is the code I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

td{ 
    padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
}

/* provide some minimal visual accomodation for IE8 and below */
th{
    background: #dae5f4;
    border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 2px 4px;
        font-weight: bold;
}

/*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
tr:nth-child(odd){ 
    background: #b8d1f3;
}

/*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
tr:nth-child(even){
    background: #dae5f4;
}

a
{
position: absolute;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<a href="http://192.168.7.102:3000/data/traffic" download="">Download</a>
<script>

var jsonURL = "http://192.168.7.102:3000/data/traffic";

d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {
    // the columns you'd like to display
    var columns = ["Clients", "Traffic", "Rank"];

    var table = d3.select("#container").append("table")
        .style("margin-top", "50px")
            .style("margin-left","280px")
            .style("border-collapse", "collapse")         // <= Add this line in.
            .style("border", "2px black solid")
            .style("width", "50%"),
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");

    // append the header row
    thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
            .text(function(column) { return column; });

    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");

    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
            .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});
</script>
```

The graph is not refreshing when data changes in the json file. 
Does anyone have any ideas on where the problem lies?

I was created node.js application and restful web service to get the data from database based on user requirement and data is written into "traffic.json" file. When the user is selected particular chart on the application we are sending that html file to the browser. In HTML d3.json function is firing.

```
Here is the code I use:
=======================
 var express = require('express'),
 http = require('http'),
 querystring = require('querystring'),
 router = express.Router(),
 fs = require('fs'),
 MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
 format = require('util').format,
 mongo = require('mongodb'),
 monk = require('monk'),
 json2csv = require('json2csv'),
 Reloader = require('reload-json'),
 reload = new Reloader();

var Start_Date ;
var End_Date ;
var Client_Ip;
var Clientip;
var ChooseData;
var Charts;
var Chart1;
var Choosedata1;
//Getting the data from calsoftlabs page
router.post('/myaction', function(req, res, next) {

     Start_Date =   req.body.StartDate +'T'+ req.body.StartTime ;
     End_Date   =   req.body.EndDate +'T'+ req.body.EndTime;
     Client_Ip  =   req.body.ClientIP;
     Clientip   =   req.body.ClientIPS;
     ChooseData =   req.body.ChooseData;
     Charts     =   req.body.Charts;
     Chart1     =   req.body.Chart;
     Choosedata =   req.body.Data;

//converting date and time to timestamp.
function evaldate(input){
var date = new Date(input);
return date.getTime();
}

var Start_timestamp = evaldate(Start_Date),

 End_timestamp = evaldate(End_Date);


var dbdata,
 start_time,
 end_time,
 client_ip,
 choosedata,
 options,
 data,
 req;
//sending parameters to restfull webapp service
if(Choosedata == "upload" || Choosedata == "download") {
 data = querystring.stringify({
      start_time: Start_timestamp,
      end_time: End_timestamp,
      client_ip: Clientip,

    });
} else if(ChooseData == "upload_traffic" || ChooseData == "download_traffic" || ChooseData == "both" ) {

data = querystring.stringify({
      client_ip: Client_Ip,
    });

}
console.log(data);

if(ChooseData == "upload_traffic") {

options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port:8080,
    path:'/restful/traffic/upload_traffic',
    method:'POST',
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

} else if(ChooseData == "download_traffic") {

options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port:8080,
    path:'/restful/traffic/download_traffic',
    method:'POST',
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};


} else if(Choosedata == "upload") {

options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port:8080,
    path:'/restful/traffic/upload',
    method:'POST',
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

}else if(Choosedata == "download"){

options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port:8080,
    path:'/restful/traffic/download',
    method:'POST',
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

} else if(ChooseData == "both") {

options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port:8080,
    path:'/restful/traffic/both',
    method:'POST',
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

}

//creating file, writing network data to a file.
var fileName = 'views/traffic.json';
req = http.request(options, function(response) {
 var jsonString = '';
 response.on('data', function(data) {
    jsonString += data;
}); 
 response.on('end',function(){
    console.log(jsonString);
    fs.writeFile(fileName, jsonString,'utf-8'); 
    });
});

if(Chart1 == 'Line') {

  res.sendfile('views/Line.html');

} else if(Chart1 == 'Bar') {

res.sendfile('views/Newbar.html');

} else if(Chart1 == 'Area') {

res.sendfile('views/Area.html');

} else if(Chart1 == 'Pie') {

res.sendfile('views/Pie.html');

} else if(Chart1 == 'Multiline') {

res.sendfile('views/Multiline.html');

} else if(Chart1 == 'All') {

res.sendfile('views/Newall.html');

} else if(Charts == 'Table') {

res.sendfile('views/Table.html');

} else if(Charts == 'StackedBar') {

res.sendfile('views/StackedBar.html')

}

req.write(data);
req.end();
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table is not refreshing because your `d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {...})` is not listening to changes to your data-file. That function will run once and that's it.

Say you rerun your data function `d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {...})` at a certain interval your next problem will be that you will never update your table but just attach a new one:

```
var table = d3.select("#container").append("table")
```

You are not selecting your table (that might already exist) but just appending a new table to the DOM. You will need to have a look at the [data binding principle in d3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

Comment: When I access the jsonURL  it is showing new data. But, this function d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {...}) is loading previous data instead of new data when data changes.

Comment: If the data changes frequently, you might be encountering a cache issue on the browser, or even the server, side. The simplest fix is changing the request URL each time.

Comment: I tried like this  var jsonURL = "http://192.168.7.102:3000/data/traffic";

d3.json(jsonURL + "?" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function(error, data) {  .  But I'm facing same issue. Its not loading new data.

Comment: Can you post the code of how you are notified of a change in the json file?  And how do you fire the 'd3.json' function once more? From the console when you see fit? I'll need a bit more info to help you out here.